# Navigation drawer to open different webviews

Tags: java, android, android-webview, navigation-drawer

working with Android I encountered this issue: how to make the navigation drawer menu list open a webview for each list item AND how to have a default webview loaded when no list item has been tapped?

I have already built the layout of the app. I have the drawer, I have the action bar, I have what must be for me the webview that should load the different URLs (managed by the drawer list items).

In the Main.java (main activity java file) I have put something like:

```
    String myUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com";

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
```

What I see is NOTHING :(

Moreover, I have very few clues about how to let the single drwer list item change URL in the webview.
Or shouldn't I proceed that way?

Any help, suggestion, tutorials would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, the project compile correctly, so there's no error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

> I have what must be for me the webview that should load the different
>   URLs (managed by the drawer list items).

Going over the training section for [`NavigationDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), it looks something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, the actual sliding menu is a `ListView`. So in your `MainActivity` you'd be doing two things:

1. Setting an adapter for this `ListView`
2. Setting an [`onItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Whenever an item is clicked, you will change the URL you load in your `WebView`.

> how to have a default webview loaded when no list item has been
>   tapped?

In your `MainActivity`, just load the default URL, simple.

Comment: does it make any difference the fact I am using AndroidStudio as IDE?

Comment: In my Main activity i have           `String myUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com";

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);`    but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple and useful example given at the android developer website for [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Please go through the sample code. In that code they load different planets images based on item click of the navigation drawer list. As far as I can understand, you need the exact same functionality. Just instead of planets images, you want to load different urls.